# Ubuntu Touch Contacts

Tags: ubuntu-touch, contacts

I have just flashed the current Ubuntu Touch image (Fri 21 Jun) and almost everything is great but i cant save contacts, this is the one thing standing between me and daily use of Ubuntu Touch does anyone know what im doing wrong or have any advice? (I can make a new contact from scratch and save one from a current conversation but after I click save then back it hasnt saved anything at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package missing in the build.

Open terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install libfolks-eds25
```

Then reboot and you should be able to save contacts again. :)